# Can I use html5 in my mobile website?

Tags: html, mobile, css

I must create a web site optimised for mobile devices, can I use html5 and css3?
What are the main limitations?
Which devices are compatible? (IOS, Android...)

Regards

Comment: What features of HTML5 are you planning to use exactly? Most of CSS3 can degrade gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - to a degree.  The website http://caniuse.com/ details HTML5 availability for the following browsers:

- iOS Safari
- Opera Mini
- Opera Mobile
- Android Browser

Answer (score 1):

You can, with some limitations. Basically you'd better use some "pre-cooked" framework like Senche Touch or jQuery Mobile.

Simple answer: the best support for HTML5 in mobile phones is given by iOS and Android browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! and about compatibity... it depends on the browser... the new versions of safari that run on the iOs 4++ support html 5...

Answer (score 0):

Back in April, [sources announced](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_gd880_mini_launched_packs_html5compatible_web_browser-news-1560.php) that LG would be the first company to launch an HTML5 compatible browser.

Where this was over 6 months ago, I haven't been able to find any other sources that woukd indicate whether any phone browsers would support it.

The best thing to do would to point your mobile device ([or emulate one](http://www.klauskomenda.com/archives/2008/03/17/testing-on-mobile-devices-using-emulators/)) to a [site made with HTML5](http://html5gallery.com/2010/11/for-the-record/).

---

After a little more research I found this quote from the [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/html5/) site.

> *"Every new Apple mobile device and every new Mac — along with the latest version of Apple’s >Safari web browser — supports web standards including HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript."*

---

Also for Android, [check this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0-highlights.html).

Answer (score 0):

iOS and Android will both support HTML5 and CSS3 (and well). You'll run into some problems with windows mobile (which runs a modified version of ie7)